# Get sub domain on AWS by IP address

Tags: dns, amazon-web-services, domain, amazon-ec2, nslookup

I have AWS Route53 zone hosted for my domain `xxx.com`.
Inside I have `A` record that maps `sub.xxx.com` to my server IP `1.2.3.4`

How can I find the `sub.xxx.com` value by just passing the IP?

I tried running: `host -a 1.2.3.4` and `nslokup 1.2.3.4` but both return just the AWS ublic DNS for the server like: `ec2-1-2-3-4.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com`.

Is there a way I can find subdomain assigned to that EC2 server by it's IP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not through DNS. The "reverse DNS" lookups that you've tried are actually querying a completely independent zone – one managed by AWS itself as the IP address owner – and while you [*can* customize rDNS on EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/reverse-dns-for-ec2s-elastic-ip-addresses/) it is not an automatic two-way relationship.

(In limited cases, if you knew the base domain name *and* if it either used NSECv1 or its nameservers allowed public zone transfer, then you could list all subdomains and grep for the ones matching your IP address. But Route53 does not use DNSSEC and by default does not allow AXFR either.)

As the zone owner, you most likely could use Route53 API for this.